# Why does this violate the type constraint?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, type-constraints, asp.net-identity-3

I'm trying to customise ASP.NET Identity 3 so that it uses integer keys:

```
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }

public sealed class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
  public ApplicationRole() { }
  public ApplicationRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, int>
{
  public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) { }
}

public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, int>
{
  public ApplicationRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) { }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
}

public sealed class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
  private static bool _created;

  public ApplicationDbContext()
  {
    // Create the database and schema if it doesn't exist
    if (!_created) {
      Database.AsRelational().Create();
      Database.AsRelational().CreateTables();
      _created = true;
    }
  }
}
```

This compiles okay, but then throws a runtime error:

> **System.TypeLoadException**
>
> GenericArguments[0], 'TeacherPlanner.Models.ApplicationUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.

The signature for `UserStore` is:

```
public class UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey>
where TUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser<TKey>
where TRole : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole<TKey>
where TContext : Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext
where TKey : System.IEquatable<TKey>
```

`ApplicationUser` is precisely an `IdentityUser<int>`. Isn't this what it's looking for?

Comment: Did you by accident declare a new type in your project with the same name as IdentityUser? I do this sometimes by picking "declare type" instead of "add using statement" in CodeRush.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ran into this problem. It was crashing on the startup.cs file.
changed

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationIdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

to

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationIdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext,int>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

declaring the key type seemed to get past the crash

Comment: I was afraid I`ll have to override all the Identity classes and methods because I have long keys, but everything works with this little fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Ran into this problem as well.  I had to add **IdentityRole** key type also, because it was still throwing the same error.

```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext,int>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note for EF Core Users**

Just to add to the above, if you are using .Net core 3.0 (not sure about earlier versions), there is no longer a `AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext,TKey>` method.

Instead there is a generic variant of `IdentityDbContext` so instead you derive your DbContext from `IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey>`

e.g. in my case

```
class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int> {...}
class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int> {...}
```

then in your startup you can use `services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`

cribbed from the last comment in https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1082