# Type Constraint Violation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Whenever I run my application, I get this error:

> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`8[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.

Here is my code snippet :

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string,ApplicationUserClaim,ApplicationUserRole,ApplicationUserLogin>

 public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole,IdentityRoleClaim<string>>

 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole,string,ApplicationUserClaim,ApplicationUserRole,ApplicationUserLogin,IdentityRoleClaim<string>,IdentityUserToken<string>>
```

And here is my startup.cs snippet on which error is thrown.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I have tried adding the key type (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018109/why-does-this-violate-the-type-constraint)) too but it didn't help.

[Link](https://github.com/shubhamranjan/Group-Based-Permissions-.NET-Core) to Full Project in case you want to test locally.

Please Help. Thank You.

EDIT:

```
   1:  public class ApplicationUserLogin: IdentityUserLogin < string > {}
   2:  public class ApplicationUserClaim: IdentityUserClaim < string > {}
   3:  public class ApplicationUserRole: IdentityUserRole < string > {}
   4:   
   5:  // Must be expressed in terms of our custom Role and other types:
   6:  public class ApplicationUser
   7:   : IdentityUser < string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin > {
   8:    public ApplicationUser() {
   9:     this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  10:   
  11:     // Add any custom User properties/code here
  12:    }
  13:   
  14:   
  15:    public async Task < ClaimsIdentity >
  16:    GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager < ApplicationUser > manager) {
  17:     var authtype = AuthenticationTypes.Basic;
  18:   
  19:     var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(await manager.GetClaimsAsync(this), authtype);
  20:     return userIdentity;
  21:    }
  22:   }
  23:   
  24:   
  25:  // Must be expressed in terms of our custom UserRole:
  26:  public class ApplicationRole:
  27:   IdentityRole < string, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityRoleClaim < string >> {
  28:    public ApplicationRole() {
  29:     this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  30:    }
  31:   
  32:    public ApplicationRole(string name): this() {
  33:     this.Name = name;
  34:    }
  35:   
  36:    // Add any custom Role properties/code here
  37:   }
  38:   
  39:   
  40:  // Must be expressed in terms of our custom types:
  41:  public class ApplicationDbContext
  42:   : IdentityDbContext < ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole,
  43:   string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin, IdentityRoleClaim < string > , IdentityUserToken < string >> {
  44:   
  45:    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options) {
  46:     Database.EnsureCreated();
  47:    }
  48:   
  49:     static ApplicationDbContext() {
  50:   
  51:    }
  52:   
  53:    //public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
  54:    //{
  55:    //    return new ApplicationDbContext();
  56:    //}
  57:   
  58:    // Add the ApplicationGroups property:
  59:     public virtual DbSet < ApplicationGroup > ApplicationGroups {
  60:     get;
  61:     set;
  62:    }
  63:   
  64:    // Override OnModelsCreating:
  65:     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  66:     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  67:   
  68:     modelBuilder.Entity < ApplicationGroup > ()
  69:      .HasMany < ApplicationUserGroup > ((ApplicationGroup g) => g.ApplicationUsers)
  70:      .WithOne()
  71:      .HasForeignKey((ApplicationUserGroup g) => g.ApplicationUserId);
  72:     modelBuilder.Entity < ApplicationUserGroup > ()
  73:      .HasKey((ApplicationUserGroup r) =>
  74:       new {
  75:        ApplicationUserId = r.ApplicationUserId,
  76:         ApplicationGroupId = r.ApplicationGroupId
  77:       });
  78:   
  79:     modelBuilder.Entity < ApplicationGroup > ()
  80:      .HasMany < ApplicationGroupRole > ((ApplicationGroup g) => g.ApplicationRoles)
  81:      .WithOne().HasForeignKey((ApplicationGroupRole ap) => ap.ApplicationGroupId);
  82:     modelBuilder.Entity < ApplicationGroupRole > ().HasKey((ApplicationGroupRole gr) =>
  83:      new {
  84:       ApplicationRoleId = gr.ApplicationRoleId,
  85:        ApplicationGroupId = gr.ApplicationGroupId
  86:      });
  87:   
  88:    }
  89:   }
  90:   
  91:   
  92:  // Most likely won't need to customize these either, but they were needed because we implemented
  93:  // custom versions of all the other types:
  94:  public class ApplicationUserStore
  95:   : UserStore < ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, DbContext, string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin, IdentityUserToken < string >> ,
  96:   IUserStore < ApplicationUser > ,
  97:   IDisposable {
  98:    public ApplicationUserStore(DbContextOptions options): this(new IdentityDbContext(options)) {
  99:     base.Dispose();
 100:    }
 101:   
 102:    public ApplicationUserStore(IdentityDbContext context): base(context) {}
 103:   
 104:    protected override ApplicationUserClaim CreateUserClaim(ApplicationUser user, Claim claim) {
 105:     throw new NotImplementedException();
 106:    }
 107:   
 108:    protected override ApplicationUserLogin CreateUserLogin(ApplicationUser user, UserLoginInfo login) {
 109:     throw new NotImplementedException();
 110:    }
 111:   
 112:    protected override ApplicationUserRole CreateUserRole(ApplicationUser user, ApplicationRole role) {
 113:     throw new NotImplementedException();
 114:    }
 115:   
 116:    protected override IdentityUserToken < string > CreateUserToken(ApplicationUser user, string loginProvider, string name, string value) {
 117:     throw new NotImplementedException();
 118:    }
 119:   }
 120:   
 121:   
 122:  public class ApplicationRoleStore
 123:   : RoleStore < ApplicationRole, DbContext, string, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityRoleClaim < string >> ,
 124:   IQueryableRoleStore < ApplicationRole > ,
 125:   IRoleStore < ApplicationRole > , IDisposable {
 126:    public ApplicationRoleStore(DbContextOptions options): base(new IdentityDbContext(options)) {
 127:     base.Dispose();
 128:    }
 129:   
 130:    public ApplicationRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context): base(context) {}
 131:   
 132:    protected override IdentityRoleClaim < string > CreateRoleClaim(ApplicationRole role, Claim claim) {
 133:     throw new NotImplementedException();
 134:    }
 135:   }
 136:   
 137:   
 138:  public class ApplicationGroup {
 139:   public ApplicationGroup() {
 140:    this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 141:    this.ApplicationRoles = new List < ApplicationGroupRole > ();
 142:    this.ApplicationUsers = new List < ApplicationUserGroup > ();
 143:   }
 144:   
 145:   public ApplicationGroup(string name): this() {
 146:    this.Name = name;
 147:   }
 148:   
 149:   public ApplicationGroup(string name, string description): this(name) {
 150:    this.Description = description;
 151:   }
 152:   
 153:   [Key]
 154:   public string Id {
 155:    get;
 156:    set;
 157:   }
 158:   public string Name {
 159:    get;
 160:    set;
 161:   }
 162:   public string Description {
 163:    get;
 164:    set;
 165:   }
 166:   public virtual ICollection < ApplicationGroupRole > ApplicationRoles {
 167:    get;
 168:    set;
 169:   }
 170:   public virtual ICollection < ApplicationUserGroup > ApplicationUsers {
 171:    get;
 172:    set;
 173:   }
 174:  }
 175:   
 176:   
 177:  public class ApplicationUserGroup {
 178:   public string ApplicationUserId {
 179:    get;
 180:    set;
 181:   }
 182:   public string ApplicationGroupId {
 183:    get;
 184:    set;
 185:   }
 186:  }
 187:   
 188:  public class ApplicationGroupRole {
 189:   public string ApplicationGroupId {
 190:    get;
 191:    set;
 192:   }
 193:   public string ApplicationRoleId {
 194:    get;
 195:    set;
 196:   }
 197:  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018109/why-does-this-violate-the-type-constraint)

Comment: I already mentioned that link `I have tried adding the key type (as mentioned here) too but it didn't help.`

Comment: @shubhamr can you show your custom ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin etc?

Comment: @tmg Edited. All Classes Visible. You may also check the full source code here.
https://github.com/shubhamranjan/Group-Based-Permissions-.NET-Core